# What am I doing wrong in this batch file?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, osql

When I run the below batch file code, it thinks that the server address is 'dbuser' and the Database is 'False'

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
set toolspath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\Application
Set ApplicationServer=00.0.00.000
Set ApplicationDatabase=dbApplication
Set ApplicationUser=dbuser
Set ApplicationPassword=abcdefg
Set ApplicationUpgradeFromPre12_5=False


REM echo "Attaching dbApplication .. "
REM osql -S %ApplicationServer% -U %ApplicationUser% -P    %ApplicationPassword% -i %ApplicationScriptsPath%\AttachApplicationDatabase.sql
REM osql -S %ApplicationServer% -U %ApplicationUser% -P %ApplicationPassword% -i %ApplicationScriptsPath%\SetDBVersion.sql
REM echo "Done."


call ApplicationUpgradeScripts.bat %%2 %ApplicationUser% %ApplicationPassword% %ApplicationDatabase% %ApplicationUpgradeFromPre12_5%
@if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto ERRORSEXIT 

@Echo %ApplicationDatabase% Database Updated Successfully.

goto FINISH


:ERRORSEXIT 
@Echo Error: Database Excecuted With Error. To Find out Exact Error see file    ErrorLog.log
exit /B 1
goto ENDBUILD 

:FINISH 
@Echo All Databases Excecuted Successfully. 
exit 0

:ENDBUILD 
pause
```

Comment: How are you calling *this* batch file, and what is %%2 supposed to be/do there?

Comment: And what is in `ApplicationUpgradeScripts.bat`?

Comment: How, do you think, should the applicationupgradescripts.bat know about your appserver?